# GPU chip implementation on CPU - will it be faster?

Tags: video, cpu

So, modern video cards include two devices - a video signal generator and a graphic accelerator.

The first of them converts data from video memory into MDA / CGA / VGA / RCA / DVI / HDMI / etc format.

The second is another co-processor (like mathematical co-processor), the purpose of which is to free the CPU from graphic calculations. This co-processor implements algorithms (as I understand it is not software but hardware) copying bits, drawing lines, scrolling, working with sprites, etc. It can implement acceleration of 2D or 3D calculations. Well, or both together.

Old computers, of course, had their own "video cards", or more precisely - video chips. If my searches are correct, not all of these "video cards" contained a video accelerator - that is, the poor CPU had to calculate the graphics completely by itself. And this includes computing graphics algorithms (Brezenham, etc.) and copying bytes. Least. For example, this is done in Atari 2600. This is a very slow way to work with graphics.

Sega Genesis, C64, Gameboy, Gameboy Color, Amiga's PC (just a couple of examples) had their own video chips for implementing graphics. Moreover, different platforms produced different graphics due to the different implementation of video chips.

So, since now I work with a homebrew for my pleasure, I can make design decisions that differ from those that were in old computers.

So, if in the system that I design, do not use video chips from old computers, but use another CPU. The program of which is independent of the main CPU and implements video algorithms -  Bresenham's, scrolling, copying bytes, etc. These algorithms, of course, I should write. And the data exchange between CPU1 and CPU2 = GPU goes through a buffer. For example, CPU1 writes to the buffer that the GPU needs to draw a line from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) or draw the desired sprite in the desired position. Well, this is an option, you can make an exchange in another way.

Will such a method be faster than classic old video chips?

For example, could Sega Genesis play heavier games if its video chip were replaced with a second Motorotola 68000 (8 Mhz) in the program of which video algorithms would be implemented?

(I understand that a direct replacement in the board will not work :) :)).
I mean, if the engineers made that decision at the design stage.)

Comment: You don't want line drawing. It's almost useless. You want copy-zooming of rectangles on either rectangles (2D) or tetragons (3D).

Comment: Nice idea, reminds me of arcade boards making use of Z80 CPUs as a sound coprocessors.

Comment: FWIW the Atari 2600 is probably the worst example you could come up with for what you described there (which is often called a “dumb frame buffer” display). The Atari 2600 didn’t have a frame buffer. It barely had anything at all. The way you do video on an Atari 2600 is nothing less than hair-raising, white-knuckle inducing.

Comment: A GPU is just a CPU that's highly optimized for its task (drawing graphics). Just like a DSP is a CPU that's highly optimized for signal processing. So replacing a GPU with a CPU of approximately same complexity and clock rate will make drawing graphics slower, not faster.

Comment: @dirkt Strictly speaking, no. A GPU is a _Graphics Processing Unit_, a CPU is a _**Central** Processing Unit_. They are both processors, yes - one is central, the other is not.

Comment: A related example would be the use of a Second Processor with a BBC Microcomputer, where the original (host) processor is dedicated to I/O tasks. In this case, the main advantage is the use of the host processor's RAM for screen memory (leaving more RAM available on the Second Processor) rather than execution speed.

Comment: The [Fujitsu FM-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM-7) had, in addition to its 6809 CPU, a second 6809 processor dedicated to graphics tasks. You might have a look at how the FM-7 compares to other contemporary systems in terms of graphics speed to get a sense of how this changed things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> For example, could Sega Genesis play heavier games if its video chip
>   were **replaced** with a second Motorotola 68000 (8 Mhz) in the program of
>   which video algorithms would be implemented?

No, it would be slower - *much* slower. The Yamaha YM7101 VDP can display 80 32x32 pixel sprites (20 per scanline), over 2 tile maps which can be freely scrolled vertically and horizontally. To do that completely in software would require many logical operations and memory accesses per pixel.

An 8MHz 68000 can barely execute 2 instructions per microsecond, and most memory operations take several microseconds. Creating those VDP functions in software would be many times slower, even with the help of a 'dumb' frame buffer. If the CPU had to do it all then it would be maxed out just trying to produce a static display, let alone scrolling and rendering sprites over it.

A CPU executes general purpose instructions, which gives it a lot of flexibility but slows it down relative to a video display 'processor' whose job is to simply push pixels out from a frame buffer. The VDP doesn't execute instructions, it has DMA buffers controlled by hardware counters that are synchronized to the video frame. Once the control registers have been set up it just continuously reads video memory and outputs pixels.

The Amiga's custom chipset is an example of a video subsystem that *does* have a processor, called the 'Copper' (short for co-processor). It only has 3 instructions - Move, Skip, and Wait, all of which are 32 bits long. Move loads an immediate value into any custom chip register, Wait waits until the beam counters reach a particular horizontal and vertical position on the screen, and Skip jumps over the next instruction if past a particular position. This is about as RISC as you can get, but it still isn't fast enough to produce a full-resolution bitmap display directly.

Comment: To clarify the problem slightly: a scan line is about 64 microseconds, or about 128 bus read or write cycles, moving a total of 256 or so bytes of memory. Given that you need to read and/or write a significant part or all  (depending on how you implement things) of the the scan line data, which might be 80 bytes for a 320-by-whatever 16-color display, plus any additional things like tile or sprite tables, plus _the opcodes themselves_, it's clear that an 8 MHz 68000 is going to be very hard pressed to do things as sophisticated as the Commodore 64, much less the Sega Genesis.

Answer (score 8):

As you surmise, one way of dividing up graphic image generation is
into two parts: building a bitmap in memory (with or without hardware
assistance) and then converting the bitmap into a video signal. And
that is how modern graphics cards do this.

Some older systems also did this, but as well there were three other
common methods of dividing up the work.

1. Instead of having a bitmap in memory, keep a "block map" that
   mapped shorter codes to small bitmaps, and use these codes to
   generate the screen image on the fly. The most common use would be
   for text screens, usually mapping a single 8-bit value to a 64-bit
   or larger bitmap, letting e.g. a 960 byte array of memory map 40x24
   character cells to a 240x192 screen image which would otherwise
   have needed 5760 bytes for a bitmap, requiring both more memory and
   more processing time if the CPU was itself filling that RAM with
   appropriate patterns for the characters.

   Text-based systems would usually have the characters/blocks in ROM;
   on some systems these were fixed, though usually there would be
   characters containing specific subpatterns that could be used to
   generate "block graphics."

   Systems supporting graphical (particularly gaming) applications
   would often allow the programmer to specify a set of custom block
   patterns in RAM.

   Systems with a block map mode might offer only that, as the
   Commodore PET and Sinclair ZX80, did. (The Z80 also offered the
   ability to have a shorter map that left out blank characters on the
   screen, so if you were displaying only a dozen short lines, your
   map would be smaller than if you had to display a full screen of
   text.) Or they might offer a choice of modes, such as the Apple II
   with a black-and-white character block mode, a 16-colour "low-res
   graphics" block mode, and a 2-4 colour bitmapped "high-res"
   graphics mode.
2. Avoid having a screen bitmap at all, and instead directly generate
   data that is eventually turned into the video signal. This is how
   the Atari 2600 worked: the CPU would load registers on the [TIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_Interface_Adaptor)
   that specified information about what was to appear on the current
   scan line, wait until the TIA had finished sending that scan line
   to the video output, reload the registers, and continue on in this
   way until a full video frame had been written. This has the
   advantage of needing no RAM to hold a screen bitmap; the Atari 2600
   had only 128 bytes of RAM in total.
3. Have a combination of the two, using either bitmap or block mode
   for the "background" of the image, but additionally generating
   further image information from other data on top of that. Often the
   extra image data generated on top of the background was a lot more
   sophisticated than the Atari 2600 example above; typically you'd
   have 8x8, 8x16 or 16x16 bitmaps called "sprites" that would be
   placed at arbitrary locations on the screen, and as well as being
   used for display the positions could be checked to see if they had
   collided and so on.

So these are the types of systems you'll be comparing with your idea
of using a coprocessor to generate graphics. You'll note that these
systems can have certain limitations on what kind of graphics they can
generate: for example, a block map system will not be able to generate
certain kinds of images that a bitmap system can generate because
typically there will not be enough different blocks to give each block
on the screen its own individual pattern. This can be worked around by
simplifying the image being generated, and this might also produce an
increase in speed of generation, but it would be up to you to decide
whether the simplified result is still acceptable for your
application.

What speed all comes down to in the end, as you compare these systems,
is how much work the CPU needs to do to generate the image. The less
data you need the CPU to move, the faster it generally works. Assuming
that your video coprocessor has full access to all of memory it should
be able to emulate any of the systems above and thus be just as fast.
If you want it to be faster, you'd need to find ways to let the CPU
send the same "instructions" to the graphics system using less memory
movement. One example might be to be able to specify vectors that the
coprocessor could render, or even go as far as a full 3D rendering
system like modern graphics cards use. These are actually a
combination of hardware and software; the developer writes small
programs ("shaders") in a special langauge that are sent to the GPU to
execute.

Here are some further resources you may find useful when thinking
about how you want to design your graphics coprocessor.

- The [Vulcan-74](https://www.atomiczombie.com/vulcan-74/) is a mostly 7400-based graphics processer that lets
  a 6502 do Amiga-level graphics. It's built with mainly 7400 series
  parts (except for its 12.5 MB of memory, for obvious reasons) on
  breadboards, and is full of good ideas for both the software
  CPU/coprocessor interface and how to actually build something like
  this. See also its [discussion thread on forums.6502.org](http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?t=3329).
- The "Pixel Processing Unit" section of [The Ultimate Game Boy
  Talk](https://youtu.be/HyzD8pNlpwI?t=1758) video provides a nice overview of the GameBoy's block
  map (here called "tile") plus sprites system, including information
  about smooth scrolling and screen overlays. This is heavily
  optimized for certain kinds of games, and gives you an idea of what
  you need to be able to compete with if you're trying to be as fast
  or faster. Take careful note of the particular structures and
  features they offer to let the CPU specify images with minimal
  processing.